# geometric view of uniform measure on the unit sphere

Tags: probability-theory

Let us consider the uniform probability measure $\mu$ on the unit sphere $S^{D-1}$ of $\mathbb{R}^D$. Next, suppose that we have a function $f: S^{D-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
Now, i want to evaluate the expectation of the random variable $f(x)$ with 
respect to the measure $\mu$.

**Question:** Intuitively, it seems that evaluating 
$\mathbb{E}_{\mu}[f(x)]$ 
should be the same as integrating the function $f(y)$ over all vectors $y \in S^{D-1}$ and then dividing with the area of $S^{D-1}$ (this latter would be a surface integral). Is this interpretation valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct interpretation.